# I can't stop puppet by using Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, puppet

After upgrading to puppet 3.8 I can't stop a puppet run by pressing Ctrl+C.

At first I thought that maybe they capture SIGINT and ignore it. But if I do a puppet run from inside a docker container, Ctrl+C works correctly.

## Edit:

This is what gets printed when I press Ctrl+C:

```
^CNotice: Caught INT; storing stop
```

Comment: That one works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending a `SIGQUIT` instead using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

---

*[There is a Puppet Labs JIRA ticket on this issue.](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-4516)*